# Model (and view) not being updated via inner function within directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs

so I've got a directive whose controller holds some user information. I've got an inner function that fetches the user info and attempts to update the controllers scope but in my view, I can't access the inner functions value.

Here is my code:

```
(function() {
  'use strict';

  angular
    .module('app')
    .directive('headerBar', headerBar);

  /** @ngInject */
  function headerBar() {
    var directive = {
      restrict: 'E',
      templateUrl: 'app/components/headerbar/headerbar.html',
      scope: {
        creationDate: '='
      },
      controller: HeaderbarController,
      controllerAs: 'vm',
      bindToController: true
    };

    return directive;

    /** @ngInject */
    function HeaderbarController($stamplay, $log) {
      var vm = this;
      var user = $stamplay.User().Model;
      vm.userInfo = {};
      vm.userInfo.displayName = "blah blah";

      user.currentUser()
        .then(function() {
          //User info
          vm.userInfo = user.instance;
          $log.info("User: " + vm.userInfo.displayName);
        });
    }
    }

    })();
```

Here are my desperate attempts to show the value. "blah blah" shows up just fine, but the actual user name while logging properly out of the function, never makes it to the model and view:

```
<input type="text" ng-value="vm.userInfo.displayName">
<div class="pull-left">
    User: {{vm.userInfo.displayName}} 
    User: {{vm.displayName}}
</div>
```

Any ideas why? Thanks a ton!

Comment: hey @mike which Stamplay SDK version are you using, 1.x or 2.x? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a digest cycle is not ran after setting the value.

Try changing the code to this:

```
function HeaderbarController($scope. $stamplay, $log) {

$scope.$apply(function() {
    vm.userInfo = user.instance;
})
```